# How to run application in debug mode and release mode with different API's in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Please help me with this issue. I have to run my application in debug mode with one API starting with and in release mode I have to run another API starting with.

In debug mode I use like this API http://def.info/api/homeapi/Login and in release mode I should use like http://abc.info/api/homeapi/Login.If I want to run in release mode or debug mode I'm changing all my API's according to that, but I know this is not the correct way to do it. Please
help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LINK_API @"LINK THAT YOU WANT"
#else
#define LINK_API @"LINK THAT YOU WANT"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a BASE URL string. This string should be set dynamically based on debug or release mode. Pre-processor macro can help you to decide the mode of the application.

Once it is ready you should create rest of the URLs based on your need.

```
NSString *baseURLString;
#ifdef DEBUG
baseURLString =  @"http://def.info/api/homeapi/";
#else
baseURLString =  @"http://abc.info/api/homeapi/";
#endif

NSString *serviceType = @"login";
NSString *loginURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURLString, serviceType];
```

Comment: It is fine.and I implemented it .But I'm getting error like
redefinition of baseurlstring with a different type:int vs nsstring * _strong